# Websphere login problems

Tags: websphere

Websphere Application Server has configured LDAP to connect to the Domino server. After the server has been restarted I can no longer access the server with the admin credential.
I can not roll back the configuration because I lost access on the server.
How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes. The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you might be seeing this problem. But if you want to get into admin console to fix your security setting, you can disable security as follows temporarily.

To disable security, please perform the following steps via wsadmin:

```
<WAS_INSTALL_DIR>/bin/> wsadmin -conntype NONE
wsadmin> securityoff
wsadmin> exit
```

Restart the servers.
Enable the security again from administrative console.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405302

Comment: Great Tamboli !
Thank you. This problem has been solved

Comment: Good to know that the problem has been solved. You can accept the answer if the information provided worked for you.